# Make the Rotation of one object Effect the Location of another Object

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm trying to rig an object, so that when I rotate one object on the X axis, it makes a different object in the scene move up on the Z axis. But I want the object's rotation to not be effected as it moves up.

**Example:** In the screenshot below, I want the cube to only move up on the Z, when the cylinder is rotated. But I don't want the cube's rotation to change.

Is there a way to do this using object constraints, or some other way?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use drivers, you can also use the *Transformation* constraint. Choose the cylinder as *Target*, enable *Extrapolate*, *Map From* > enable *Rotation* and set the values you want on Y as it's the Y rotation of the cylinder that will matter, *Map To* > choose *Location* and  *Z Source > Y* as you want the Z location to be influenced by the Y rotation of the cylinder:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you!